# saving content containing html tags and single double quotes into database

Tags: php, html, mysql

i've table with fields X:headline,content ,time.

through htmlform i upload data into this table.
html is:

```
<form action="process2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Headline: <input name="headline" type="text" size="100" /><br /><br />
Content:<textarea name="content" cols="100" rows="10" placeholder="Content here">
</textarea><br /><br />
</form>
```

part of process2 php script:

```
$headl = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['headline']);
$headline=htmlspecialchars("$headl", ENT_QUOTES);

$cont=$_POST['content'];
$cont = str_replace("&lt;", "<", $cont);
$cont = str_replace("&gt;", ">", $cont);
$content=htmlentities($cont,ENT_QUOTES);

$sql="INSERT INTO X(`headline`, `content`, `date`) VALUES ('$headline','$content',NOW())";

$query = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
```

problem:
Headline and date are getting inserted. 
whereas content remains empty...

i've tried mysql_real_escape_string on content also but no use.
why content is empty? ...any solution?

Comment: why aren't you using mysql_real_escape_string on content too?

Comment: Use a prepared statement.

Comment: try echo `$content` and see what it gives. maybe its empty before inserting to database

Comment: @echo_me   ya its empty before entering into database

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario how sql injection came inbetween... this html and php script is for admin, it wont be accessible to user..

Comment: then echo `$cont` and see also , you should know how to debug by yourself

Comment: @user2320375 - If you say so then you don't fully understand what SQL injection is. I'll put an analogy: you don't let your code divide by zero just because it's for internal use, do you?

Comment: you found `$cont` the problem was there ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, it should work in your situation:

```
// htmlspecialchars Must with ENT_QUOTES, it actually make mysql_real_escape_string useless, but mysql_real_escape_string for safe anyway.

$headline = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['headline'], ENT_QUOTES));
$content = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['content'], ENT_QUOTES));

$sql = "INSERT INTO X(`headline`, `content`, `date`) VALUES ('{$headline}', '{$content}', NOW())";

$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

To display, you can load out the data from mysql, and perform htmlspecialchars_decode for each.

And more simple way is, don't do htmlspecialchars when saving them, just like this:

```
$headline = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['headline']);
$content = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['content']);
```

After mysql_real_escape_string, data should be safe for mysql, because all known inject trick will be filtered. You only need to care about the html content it self. Oh, and the length of the both content must not break the char limit of your fields.